# Variable names in Django-REST and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django-rest-framework, naming-conventions

This is a design question rather than a programming problem:
Django (Python) has the variable naming convention of `a_var_in_python`
On the other hand, AngularJS (Javascript) has the camelCase convention `thisIsMyVar`

When I consume with AngularJS from my Django-REST API, I get a response like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "owner": "Amir",
        "quantity_last_seen": "2015-11-18",
        "part_number": "HT283X",
        "description": "Some regular item I think is good",
        "quantity": 10,
        "minimum_quantity": 4,
        "rohs": true,
        "component_tech": "None",
        "created_at": "2015-11-26T19:14:18.289000",
        "updated_at": "2015-11-30T22:38:30.138000"
    }
]
```

When I consume in angular, my response's payload will be stored in a local var 
`vm.item`

Now, when I print information from `vm.item` (and remember, that's in the Angular side),
i use `{{ vm.item.part_number }}`, that is NOT Javascriptic.

What do you suggest should be done, IF anything should be done - which could keep each language's naming convention?

Comment: https://github.com/domchristie/humps

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm afraid should we do this(Using this library and using that) in large project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [github.com/domchristie/humps](http://github.com/domchristie/humps) to convert the objects to camelCase.